# Cannot add library in VC++ 2008: My System is Different

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2008, project-reference

Hopefully someone can tell me what's going on here.  I'm trying to link to gdiplus.lib and I tried to go to "Properties - Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies" to add the library but I do NOT have that section.  I'm using Visual C++ 2008.  Here's what I see:

- Common Properties

  - Framework and References
- Configuration Properties

  - General
  - Degugging
  - C/C++
  - Librarian
  - Resources
  - XML Document Generator
  - Browse Information
  - Build Events
  - Custom Build Step

I've checked every subcategory and there is NOT a "Linker" section or an "Input" section.  Once again, this is Visual C++ 2008 without any customizations or strange settings.  I have a screenshot at http://drp.ly/13ma9l if anybody's interested.

How come my Property panel is completely different than everyone else's?  Typical Microsoft crap I suppose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Linker" section changes to "Librarian" if the project is set to compile as a static library. Make sure Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type is set to "Application (.exe)" and not to "Static Library (.lib)." Click "Apply" to save the changes.

The "Librarian" section does have an "Additional Dependencies" field. Use that instead of the "Linker" section.

Comment: The project is wxWidgets - it has to be a library.  It's simply that it needs gdiplus.lib but I can't figure out where to add it because all the instructions are for applications, apparently.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't need it: http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/9630 Unless you're using a different version?

Comment: It does if you use wxUSE_GRAPHICS_CONTEXT which I need.  It works fine on Mac OS X, but the Windows version has it enabled by default.  To enable it you need gdiplus.lib.  Which again, I'm not sure where to add it.

Comment: Ah, didn't see your edit.  Is this supposed to be correct?  http://drp.ly/13mB8F  It doesn't work... it's still missing the gdiplus library after being compiled.  If that's supposed to work then the wxWidgets project file is bad.

Comment: Would it matter that I'm using Windows 7 32-bit?

Comment: What's the specific compiler error? It's possible you don't have a `gdiplus.lib` in your development environment.

Comment: Here's my thread over on the wxWidgets forum: http://cl.ly/c878f7065ee57aa481a0
Look at the 4th post - I took 4 screenshots of some of the error messages (for some reason Visual Studio won't let me copy them).

EDIT: I decided to just put the 4 screenshots here but you can look through that thread too if you want to: 
http://drp.ly/13ihad | http://drp.ly/13ikax | http://drp.ly/13il13 | http://drp.ly/13inbE |

Comment: And if gdiplus.lib isn't in the development environment, then where is it?  I did a complete install of Visual Studio; if that doesn't install all the frameworks then there's a serious snafu on Microsoft's part...

Comment: Aha... Auria figured it out over on the wxForum - it looks like I tried to add the library to wxWidgets (makes sense, right, since it's the framework that depends on it?) but in reality it's my application needs to add it.  Ugh.  That's why I like the Mac; I just compile, and everything works.  :)

Comment: Glad to know that you found your solution. But I'm going to be a nitpick and say that this is simply a configuration issue, not an Apple/Microsoft issue. :-) Next time you ask a question like this, be sure to post the exact compiler error in the question. It will help the rest of us.

Comment: True, at first I didn't think it was a config issue, but just an issue with importing libraries.  Obviously that wasn't it.  Thanks again for your help though - I learned a thing or two about Visual Studio along the way.  Not that I use it much, but on the few occasions that I do, it'll help.  I'll still be sticking with Cocoa/Xcode for my own programs though.  :)